# How to disable GPS in ROS/MAVROS and sent the points myself?

Tags: ros, gazebo

I'm trying to create a simple `MAVROS` node that takes off, goes to a specific location and then comes back to its home location. As this is currently being tested inside `Gazebo`it uses fake gps. I now want to publish the GPS coordinates myself, and thus need to disable the existing fake gps that keeps publishing.

I could publish my gps locations (lat, lon, alt) through `mavros/global_position/global` topic and then read from it. I want to disable that and see if my quadrotor does go to a custom gps point that I send it to.
I also noticed there is something called `mocap=true` in `rosparam` list. Should I disable this as well or I'd be fine to leave it as is? if so how can I do that as well?

**Note:**
The GPS coordinates that I'm publishing are not something random. They are created using a combination of other sensors. so they are accurate, maybe not as accurate as the original GPS coordinates, but I believe they are accurate enough. that's why I asked, how I can disable the fake gps that gazebo/mavros/ros(not sure which one) is also publishing, so I can test my generated coordinates properly.
In other words, I want the `mavros/global_position/global` to only contain my published coordinates. currently, in gazebo/mavros there is a fake gps that also is publishing coordinates on this topic whenever I start simulating. I want to stop this

Answer (score 1):

There will be a slight problem with that because the custom GPS point you give might be far from the current GPS coordinate at which the drone is present. I'm assuming you are using px4 autopilot(or ardupilot). I think you cannot publish to `/mavros/global_position/global`. You should publish your setpoints to `/mavros/setpoint_position/global` topic. So when you switch to `offboard` mode, then `takeoff` and publish your setpoint to the above topic. Then the drone will reach the position of your input. You can try to see the drone's home position using the QGroundControl app and then adjust your custom setpoint accordingly. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The GPS points will be accurate. the thing is, my board does not have a gps sensor, and therefore I'm trying to provide the gps coordinates myself, so that I can set the target coordinate using `mavros/setpoint_position/global` and move the quadrotor to target. I believe without doing this "setpoint_position/global" can not be used, as the current coordinate will be unkown. am I wrong?

Comment: So you want to navigate the drone to the target which is published at the `mavros/setpoint_position/global` and also want to check if your drone has reached the goal or not without using any GPS data? Is that what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes. thats pretty much it.

Comment: Then calculate the heading angle and the distance. Once the drone takes off, publish a velocity message to adjust its heading angle and then publish the velocity setpoint with value `v` to the drone. When `v*time` reaches the distance, get the drone to stop. You can't publish a GPS point without the drone having any info about GPS. It constantly checks itself if it's reached the setpoint, so without GPS data, it can't. Either you fake the GPS or use the heading angle and distance.

Comment: Thanks, It seems I didnt convey myself properly. the gps coordinates that I'm publishing is not something random. its created through a combination of other sensors. so its accurate, not as accurate as the gps, but I believe accurate enough. thats why I asked, how I can disable the fake gps that gazebo/mavros/ros is also publishing, so I can test my generated coordinates properly. 
I cant seemply calculate the heading and go that direction as drifts will happen, and without knowing where exactly the drone is I cant know for sure if its going into the right direction. hence going the gps route

Comment: I want the `mavros/global_position/global` only contain my published coordinates only. currently, inside gazebo/mavros/ there is a fake gps thats also publishing coordinates. I want to stop this.

Comment: So you will know the drone's GPS position(not accurately but). You want to publish your own GPS data on the `global` topic. Is that what you want to do? You can disable the fake GPS by going into `mavros/mavros/launch/px4_config.yml` there will be a fake GPS segment and you can remove it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give that a try. I'll report back on what ensued.

Comment: I did that but it seems gazebo also sends out gps coords as well(the world gps coord is being published constantly), do you happen to know how I can disable gps in gazebo as well?

Comment: There's a global position part above the fake GPS. Try to remove it. But I exactly don't know about it.